# startActivityForResult with an enum

Tags: java, android, eclipse, enums

I am writing an android app, and I have a home screen that starts different playing modes (different activites). I want to start each activity for a result using
`startActivityForResult()` with the requestCode being equal to some constant for each type of the game (easy, medium, hard). I was trying to do this with an enum, but eclipse is telling me `startActivityForResult(Intent i, int request code) is not applicable for arguments (Intent, [name of my enum class])`. I tried to implement this with an inner class, but it does not work.

I was hoping to utilize enums so that the code is more readable in onActivityResult() (i.e. checking if resultCode == EASY rather than resultCode == 1).

From my understanding, Enums act the same as integers. Correct me if I am wrong.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

you can create a final variable to for each type as:

```
final int EASY =0;
final int MEDIUM= 0;
```

and use those values in your code.

Comment: I was hoping to utilize enums so that the code is more readable in `onActivityResult()` (i.e. checking if resultCode == EASY rather than resultCode == 1).

Comment: Oh. Using final variables will allow you to use the make the code readable. you can use resultCode == EASY since EASY will equal=1 everywhere in that activity. I meant  to say that the final variable should be created at the activity level

Comment: Whoops, my mistake, you're right. Is it possible to use enums here?

Comment: As far as I know, I do not think so because it required an int, and enum is its own type.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this with a little more work:

```
public enum MyActivityResult {
    OK(0),
    CANCELED(1),
    SOMETHING_ELSE(2)
    UNKNOWN(3);

    public final int value;

    MyActivityResult(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public static MyActivityResult fromValue(int value) { 
        for (MyActivityResult result : values()) {
            if (result.value == value) return result;
        }
        return UNKNOWN;
    }
}
```

Then, in your `Activity`:

```
setResult(MyActivityResult.SOMETHING_ELSE.value);
finish();
```

And in your `onActivityResult()`:

```
MyActivityResult result = MyActivityResult.fromValue(resultCode);
```

It's a lot of extra code, honestly, and you still end up passing an integer (i.e. an `Activity` isn't required to send a valid result) so I wouldn't necessarily suggest doing this, but it is one way if you wanted to add behavior to the results.